# vue.js how to organize front-end data (e.g. product information)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What is the correct pattern to store e.g. static product information data within a vue2 single page application?

Previously I've used an external js file that included a JSON with product-attributed (e.g. name, weight, height etc).

I don't want to load via AJAX since the spa needs to work without a web-server.

Comment: you can store it in a VueX getter.

Answer (score 1):

While [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) is meant to provide to a single source of truth for dynamic data throughout your single page application, I think it's also the proper and clean way of storing static data. VueX allows you to write getters and setters (as mutations / actions), now if you simply leave those setters out of your module you'll have a centralized store module that is read-only but available in every component.

**Why is that better than just using a static JSON file?**

Using a JSON file will expose the entire content to every single component that uses that file. In some cases that might be what you want, but it's by far not as flexible as having multiple getters that allows you to define the exact scope of what each component should receive. Also VueX uses all observable patterns and best practices from Vue itself, so the integration of your data in for example computed properties is super easy. Due to the getters pattern you'll also be able to define any kind of filtering or sorting in one place that you can share in your entire application. While that might not be what you need right now, keep in mind your requirements may change over time and simply having the option to easily implement that later is also a good thing. Same goes for reading the data from an Endpoint instead of having it statically. Your application might not need that right now, but in case you want to do that somewhen in the future, vuex will make it super easy to transition to dynamic data without you having to change any component.

**What speaks against VueX?**

Not that much. While it's a little bit of overhead if you really only use it for static data, the possible scalability it offers you is worth that minor downside.